# Use ng-value for radio button (angularjs)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'am new with angularjs.. 
I want to make a selection using radio button and save as `boolean` value.
When I use `ng-value`, then the value save into database is `null`. This is the code for html.

```
<label><input type="radio" ng-model="information" ng-value="TRUE" name="maklumat">Yes</label><br />
<label><input type="radio" ng-model="information" ng-value="FALSE" name="maklumat">False</label>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**`ng-value`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bradio%5D) expects **AngularJS expression** to which ngModel will be be set when the radio is selected.

And expressions being case-sensitive, if you set `ng-value="true"` it sets your what you have in `ng-model` to `true`, but if you have `ng-value="TRUE"`, it tries to get `$scope.TRUE` which it doesn't find and your `ng-model` gets set to `null`.

Here's an example.

```js
angular.module('radioExample', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.TRUE = "something totally different"
    $scope.specialValue = {
      "id": "12345",
      "value": "green"
    };
  }]);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-radio-input-directive-production</title>
  <script src="//code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="radioExample">

  <form name="myForm" ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <label>
    <input type="radio" ng-model="color.name" ng-value="specialValue">
    SpecialValue
  </label><br/>
    <label>
    <input type="radio" ng-model="color.name" ng-value="true">
    true
  </label><br/>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" ng-model="color.name" ng-value="TRUE">
    TRUE
  </label><br/><br/>
    <tt>color = {{color.name | json}}</tt><br/>
  </form>
  <br><br/><br/> Note that `ng-value="specialValue"` sets radio item's value to be the value of `$scope.specialValue`.
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Actually, if he wanted a boolean value it's better to use `ng-value` as it execute the value to be a boolean rather than a string. Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tur9582o/3/) for an example. To expand on this as well in the documentation you've linked it says _ng-value should be used instead of the value attribute if you need a non-string ngModel (boolean, array, ...)._

Answer (score 4):

The issue is with what you've entered in the `ng-value` value, just change them to lower case like so.

```
<label>
    <input type="radio" ng-model="information" ng-value="true" name="maklumat">Yes
</label>
<br />
<label>
    <input type="radio" ng-model="information" ng-value="false" name="maklumat">False
</label>
```

[Fiddle for example](http://jsfiddle.net/tur9582o/4/)

**EDIT 1**

The reason it is saving as null is because it's trying to evaluate the value `FALSE` which is undefined.

Comment: Also it is better to assign a default value to `$scope.information=false` in controller (for this case as the data is going in database).